# Pulling parts of JSON out to display them in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON:

```
var questions = {
    section: {
        "1": question: {
            "1": {
                "id" : "1a",
                "title": "This is question1a"
            },
            "2": {
                "id" : "1b",
                "title": "This is question2a"
            }
        },
        "2": question: {
            "1": {
                "id" : "2a",
                "title": "This is question1a"
            },
            "2": {
                "id" : "2b",
                "title": "This is question2a"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**NOTE: JSON changed based on the answers below to support the question better as the original JSON was badly formatted and how it works with the for loop below.**

The full JSON will have 8 sections and each section will contain 15 questions.

The idea is that the JS code will read what section to pull out and then one by one pull out the questions from the list. On first load it will pull out the **first question** and then when the user clicks on of the buttons either option A or B it will **then load in the next question until all questions have been pulled and then do a callback.**

When the button in the appended list item is clicked it will then add it to the list below called responses with the answer the user gave as a span tag.

This is what I have so far:

```
    function loadQuestion( $section ) {

    $.getJSON('questions.json', function (data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var item = data[i];

        if (item === $section) {
            $('#questions').append('<li id="' + item.section.questions.question.id + '">' + item.section.questions.question.title + ' <button class="btn" data-response="a">A</button><button class="btn" data-response="b">B</button></li>');
        }
    }
});

}

    function addResponse( $id, $title, $response ) {

        $('#responses').append('<li id="'+$id+'">'+$title+' <span>'+$response+'</span></li>');

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // should load the first question from the passed section
        loadQuestion( $('.section').data('section') );

        // add the response to the list and then load in the next question
        $('button.btn').live('click', function() {

            $id = $(this).parents('li').attr('id');
            $title = $(this).parents('li').html();
            $response = $(this).data('response');

            addResponse( $id, $title, $response );

            loadQuestion ( $('.section').data('section') );

        });

    });
```

and the HTML for the page (each page is separate HTML page):

```
<div class="section" data-section="1">

            <ul id="questions"></ul>

            <ul id="responses"></ul>

        </div>
```

I've become stuck and confused by how to get only the first question from a section and then load in each question consecutively for that section until all have been called and then do a callback to show the section has been completed.

Thanks

Comment: you said u have 8 sections are the label for all of them 'Section' only in ur json data???

Comment: data-section="1", data-section="2" do not count as unique if each one still says <div id="section">. ID must be unique, nothing else matters if the ID is duplicated. If ID is duplicated, it is broken.

Comment: The JSON itself has the same label and that's wrong

well the id is inside the object and coz u have the same section label the last one is gonna override all the other section above.

Comment: Only one div with the id of section will exist per page!

Comment: div class="section" is ok but div id="section" is invalid. Also if you have var myobj = {section: 1, section: 2, section:3} it is INVALID whereas var myobj = {section1: 1, section2: 2, section3:3} is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not have multiple id's in html called "section."
2. Do not have multiple keys in your JSON on the same level called "section". Keys in JSON on the same level should be unique just as if you are thinking about a key-value hash system. Then you'll actually be able to find the keys. Duplicate JSON keys on the same level is not valid.

One solution can be section1, section2, etc. instead of just section. Don't rely on data-section attribute in your HTML - it's still not good if you have "section" as the duplicate html id's and as duplicate JSON keys.

If you have only one section id in HTML DOM, then in your JSON you must also have just one thing called "section" e.g.:

```
var whatever = {
                    "section" : { 
                               "1":  {
                                        "question" : {
                                                       "1" : {
                                                          "id" : "1a",
                                                          "title" : "question1a"
                                                              },
                                                       "2" : {
                                                          "id" : "2a",
                                                          "title"  : "question2a"
                                                              }
                                                     }
                                      },                                 
                                "2":  {
                                        "question" : {
                                                       "1" : {
                                                          "id" : "1a",
                                                          "title" : "aquestion1a"
                                                              },
                                                       "2" : {
                                                          "id" : "2a",
                                                          "title"  : "aquestion2a"
                                                              }
                                                     }
                                      }
                                 }
               }
console.log(whatever.section[1].question[1].title); //"question1a"
```

To get question, do something like this:

```
   function loadQuestions(mySectionNum) {

       $.getJSON('whatever.json', function(data){

        var layeriwant = data.section[mySectionNum].question;

           $.each(layeriwant, function(question, qMeta) {
               var desired = '<div id="question-' + 
                              qMeta.id +
                              '"' + 
                              '>' + 
                              '</div>';
               $("#section").append(desired);
               var quest = $("#question-" + qMeta.id);
               quest.append('<div class="title">' + qMeta.title + '</div>');
               //and so on for question content, answer choices, etc.
           });



       });
   }
```

then something like this to actually get the questions:

```
    function newQuestion(){
       var myHTMLSecNum = $("#section").attr('data-section');
       loadQuestions(myHTMLSecNum);
    }

    newQuestion();

  //below is an example, to remove and then append new question:

    $('#whatevernextbutton').on('click',function(){
       var tmp = parseInt($("#section").attr('data-section'));
       tmp++;
       $("#section").attr('data-section', tmp);
       $("#section").find('*').remove();
       newQuestion();
    });
```

Comment: There is only one html element called section! The pages are called using AJAX so only exists per document! Can you help reformat the JSON data? Thanks

Comment: Then in JSON you must have only one key called "section," see my reworked answer with example.

Comment: Thanks for the reformatted JSON. So based on the question, how would I get the first question ONLY for the page section and then on each click of the button load the next question until it reaches the last question and does a callback that the section has finished. Thanks for all your help. I've updated my question with the latest version of my code based on your answer.

Comment: use the data-section attribute on your HTML page to help you get the right section number :) Then, use an $.each loop to loop through that part of the JSON object (i.e. whatever.section[YOURNUMBER].questions.length  -- something along the lines of that. For easier looping, change "1a" into "1", "2" "3", and so on and then inside that object put id: "1a", id: "1b", etc.

Comment: Can you show an example for how I would do that in my loadQuestion function? As I'm really confused with this part of the code. Thanks again. Really appreciated.

Comment: I changed the JSON to be with the inner question numbers to be"1", "2", and so on - it's easier to loop that way. If you need the real "id" to put on the page now it is inside as "id" attribute.

Comment: Cool that makes more sense :) Could you show an example of pulling this data using the for loop though? Still not being able to pull the data using the for loop I have posted in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: I put example. By the way because I use JQuery in my example, it will actually be OK even if the questions are named "1a", "2a" etc - but in that case if you change it back to that original JSON format, then my code example will need to be changed as well, my code example assumes the JSON I posted above it. Hope this helps!

Comment: PS I am assuming like you said that AJAX loading only one section at a time - I am assuming that you have HTML as originally posted before you changed it just now - i.e. about having it ID not CLASS, as in: <div id="section" data-section="1"> if you want it to be class="section" you need to change my code example but hopefully my example gives you a base idea how to go about it.

Comment: btw I noticed the JSON question update you did based on my code is incorrect - I made a mistake the first time and what it shows now is correct JSON so make sure you change your JSON file to my updated code as well. Remember that anything nested has to be wrapped yet again in curly braces as it is another JS object layer. Wherever it says "myprop1": "prop1": "hello" it MUST be instead "myprop1": {"prop1": "hello"} for instance

Comment: P.S. just had another idea (maybe you already did this) - why not load the JSON just once the very first time someone gets to your quiz on the first question, and at that moment cache it in some custom object in the DOM such as "myQuestions", and then next time, if the cached object already exists in the DOM and has properties, then you just use that object instead of doing getJSON every single time? Perhaps an if statement in loadQuestion that checks for your DOM object would suffice, and to actually store the object, just add something like window['myQuestionsCache'] = data; in getjson

Answer (score 1):

Technically your `getJSON` function always retrieves the same data. Your code never compares the id given to the id you're extracting.

Your getJSON should look something like:

```
function loadQuestion( $section ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.section.length; i++) {

            var item = questions.section[i];
            if (item.id === $section) {
                for (var j = 0; j < item.questions.length; j++) {
                    $('#questions').append('<li id="' + 
                        item.questions[i].id + '">' + 
                        item.questions[i].title + 
                        ' <button class="btn" data-response="a">A</button><button class="btn" data-response="b">B</button></li>'
                    );
                }
           }
        }
}
```

Modify your JSON to:

```
var questions = {
    section: [{
        id: 1,
        questions: [{
            id: "1a",
            title: "This is question1a"
            },{
            id: "2a",
            title: "This is question2a"
        }]},{
        id: 2,
        questions: [{
            id: "1a",
            title: "This is question1a"
            },{
            id: "2a"
            title: "This is question2a"
        }]
    }]
};
```

Edit: your first parameter of [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is the URL of the JSON returning service.

You don't need getJSON at all if your JSON is already defined on the client. I have modified the code above.

Comment: The JSON you see in the original post :)

Comment: I'm getting the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` on the second for loop. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Now it has been fixed. I forgot to increment j

Comment: Don't wrap it. Your questions object exists on the page doesn't it?

Comment: No I use getJSON to load the list of questions from a JSON file called `questions.json` and then I want to pull out the questions one by one on a button click from the correct section.

Comment: Then make sure that you're providing the correct path to questions.json and that there aren't any access issues. Profile this using the network profiler of your browser.

Comment: Hmm, the JSON is returned correctly. However the breakpoint inside the success is never hit. You also need to assign questions to data inside your success callback.

Comment: remove var questions = and leave only the JSON object. See if this would do anything.